# Aliexpress detecting automated browser, human verification fail in Selenium chrome driver

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, automation, webdriver, aliexpress

I want to write a script to scrap some data from aliexpress, so I need to be logged in first, When I try to login, Aliexpress ask for slide to verify sometimes, I made an script to do this in an automated way using selenium actions, but it gives the following error:

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1Mqu.png)

Well, I tried to it manually, But I am getting the same error, so it seems somehow aliexpress is detecting that its running in an automated environment, so please can you help me to avoid that.

Resources I used:
I used chrome_driver with brave browser and chrome but both didn't work.